# Symantic Version Numbering After Changing Package Manager

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

In regards to Symantic Versioning, if I changed my package manager on an existing project (Laravel) from bower to npm, should i increment my app version to:

`1.1.X` to `1.2.X`

or just

`1.1.1` to `1.1.2`

I have read that if it's just a feature, just change the middle digit.

But if it would break the application, the first digit should be the one incremented.

I believe my situation would break the application, any confirmation on this or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it does not play any role in your application, you should not just anything. That's not even a feature, you just changed your package manager.

Comment: i think it does brother. even back-end activities should affect your version numbering.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be fine to just change it to 1.1.x.